# Returning a stored procedure, ado, access, vba

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, sql-server-2000

I have the following stored procedure.

```
create procedure dbo.sp_getDailyStats 
    @Rundate varchar(10), @PrevRunDate  varchar(10) OUTPUT
as 
Declare @Claims bigint;
declare @Days bigint;
declare @Claims_Completed_prev bigint;
declare @Claim_inventory bigint;
declare @Inv30 bigint;
declare @Inv30NP bigint
declare @InvNP bigint

set @PrevRundate=convert(varchar(10),dbo.getPreviousBusinessDate(@Rundate),101)

----- not the whole code.
```

I run it from the command line like this:

```
declare @myvare varchar(10)
declare @InputDate varchar(10)
set @InputDate='06/10/2015'
exec dbo.sp_getDailystats @InputDate, @myvare output

select @myvare; and it returns the previous date to @myware but I have to put output on that line to make it work.
```

Below is my ado code:

```
Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Dim Newdate As String
Newdate = "06/10/2015"
Dim Prevdate As String

cn.Open "Provider=sqloledb; " & _
"Data Source=" & "BLD-FS-SQLVS01\PRDINST1, 4020" & ";" & _
"Initial Catalog=" & "HNFS_NetProv" & ";" & _
"Integrated Security=SSPI;"

Set cmd.ActiveConnection = cn
cmd.CommandText = "sp_getDailyStats"
cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

cmd.Parameters(1) = Newdate


rs.CursorType = adOpenStatic
rs.CursorLocation = adUseClient
rs.LockType = adLockOptimistic
Set rs = cmd.Execute

Prevdate = cmd(2)


Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

Ado automatically recognizes that I have two parameters but it is not returning cmd(2)

So how do I get my value to show up?  All the examples I see want me to add/create parameters which I don't need to do.  I just need to have the paramenter show up but I don't have a way of putting output on the procedure.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Comment: The result your are SELECT'ing out of the procedure isn't an out parameter. It's a result set, just as if you were selecting a single field from an actual table. Look at what might be in "rs" after the Execute() statement.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of confusion here about output parameters and resultsets. You are wanting to capture the value of @myvare that is SELECT'ed out of your procedure; that is not an "out parameter," but a simple result set just as if you'd SELECTed it from a regular table. It should be captured among any other result sets within the "rs" variable in your client program.

In contrast, an *output parameter* is one defined as one of the parameters to the procedure with an OUTPUT qualifier, and is defined to a `SqlCommand` object as a `SqlParameter` with a Direction of `Output`. You won't get the value of the OUTPUT parameter from the procedure in your client code if you don't define it before execution, then inspect it's value after the procedure returns, something along the lines of the following (after the 1st parameter definition and before the Execute):

```
SqlParameter prevRunDate = new SqlParameter("@PrevRunDate", SqlDbType.VarChar);
prevRunDate.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
prevRunDate.Size = 10;
cmd.Parameters.Add(prevRunDate);
```

Comment: Dim prevRunDate As Parameter
Set prevRunDate = cmd.CreateParameter("@PrevRunDate", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 10)
'prevRunDate.Direction = adParamOutput
'prevRunDate.Size = 10
'prevRunDate.Size = 10;
cmd.Parameters.Append prevRunDate

Comment: When I put the above code in I get the following.  BTW, this is Access2010 vba against sql 2000 sqlserver backend.

Comment: I got it to work with the following: cmd.Parameters(2).Direction = adParamOutput
 cmd.Execute
Prevdate = cmd(2)

Comment: Great! Glad I was able to at least give you a hint in the right direction. Apologies for having put up C# examples - oversight on my part!